# How to add 2 numbers inside a list using vue.js

Tags: javascript, java, list, vue.js, addition

How can I add the first 5 numbers that my list take from the url and then calcuate the average . What i mean is taking the average values per 5 minutes , 30 minutes,60 minutes. I made a delay 1 minute so at the first 5 minutes in my list there should be 5 values.
Then I want to show in 3 different templates the average of the values I take.

```
<template>
  

<div id="app" >
  
 
  <form>
    
    <label>Enter Currency: <input type="text" v-model="currency"></label>
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Submit"  @click="getData(currency) "/>
    
    
    
    
  </form>
  
  <pre></pre><p>Bitcoin Value is : {{ apiData?.data?.amount }}</p>
  

  <template v-for="value in getShortList(5)">
    <pre></pre><p>Last 5 minute value is : {{ }} </p>
    <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
  </template>

  <template v-for="item in getShortList(29)">
    <pre></pre><p>Last 30 minute value is : {{parseInt (getShortList(29))}}</p>
    <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
  </template>

  <template v-for="item in getShortList(59)">
    <pre></pre><p>Last 60 minute value is : {{ parseInt (getShortList(59)) }}</p>
    <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
  </template>



 

  <template>
<div>
  <apexchart width="500" type="bar" :options="options" :series="amountList"></apexchart>
</div>
</template>



  
</div>



</template>
```

My script code is above:

```
 import axios from 'axios'
 

export default {
  
 
 
  data() {
    return {
      apiEndPoint : 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=',
      apiData: [],
      amountList: [],
      
       
      
      
      
    
    }
  },
  

  created () {
   


    
    this.getData(this.currency);

   
   
  }
,
 
  

  methods: {
    getShortList(shortListSize) {
      return this.amountList.slice(0, shortListSize);
      
     

    },

    

    getData(currency) {

     
      axios.get(`${this.apiEndPoint}${currency}`).then((response) => {
        
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
   
        this.apiData = response.data
        this.amountList.push(response.data.data.amount)
        

        console.log(this.amountList)
      }, 5000) 
        })
       
    
  
        
    
      }
      
    }
  }


  


   
</script>
```

Comment: What is the use of calling same endpoint after every 5 seconds ? You can fetch all the response in a single go and then splice as per the requirement.

Comment: how i can do that? The purpose is taking the bitcoin value every  1 minute not every 5 seconds . i Just used 5 seconds for testing

Comment: The response values will be changed after 1 minute because they get collected from a live json api

Comment: And after that  I want to slice the first 5 values but return the average value of them 5 combined

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding and by the comments you added, You are facing challenge in getting the average of the array (`this.amountList`) items. If Yes, you can achieve that with the help of [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
// spliced amountList which contains 5 items.  
const arr = [100, 200, 30, 44, 50];

// Find the average
const average = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length;

// output
console.log(average);
```

Once you get the average, You can make this reactive by assigning the value to a data object property.

Comment: OK I understood it so I should make 3 const arr each one containing 5, 30, 60 values right? And taking the average of them each time

Comment: No, Just for a demo I created an `arr` variable but in your case you are splicing `amountList` dynamically based on `shortListSize`. In `getShortList` method only you can calcualte the average dynamically.

Comment: I tried it but I can't take the 5 values from my list in the getShortList  method so I can make the average like u recommended me

Comment: as you are passing dynamic number in the method you can slice the array based on that and in that case you will get dynamic array elements only by splicing based on the passed param.